# How to install cartopy on windows

Tags: conda, cartopy

I tried command: pip3 install cartopy on my windows, but it doesn't work and it hints me:

```
  setup.py:171: UserWarning: Unable to determine GEOS version. Ensure you have 3.3.3 or later installed, or installation may fail.
    '.'.join(str(v) for v in GEOS_MIN_VERSION), ))
  Proj 4.9.0 must be installed
```

Then I tried to install it through conda command and it seems that it works for the conda list shows the presentation of cartopy libarary. However, when I import cartopy, it hints me:

```
No Module Named cartopy
```

Comment: It sounds like when you run Python, you're not running the version of Python installed with conda, but another version.

Answer (score 0):

To install cartopy, you need GEOS v3.3.3 or later and Proj 4.9.0 or later.

I couldn't install both packages with pip but with conda. I also had conda installed with pip and continually was giving me an error with menuinst. If this is also your case, to solve it, you must uninstall conda with pip and reinstall it, downloading it from website. Since you are using windows, you can get it from here:

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/windows.html

Once you has conda installed, do:

```
conda install Proj
conda install GEOS
```

And then, you can do

```
conda install cartopy
```

I hope it helps.

(if you install the packages with conda, don't forget to tell your IDE, to use the python installed with conda).